# How is it possible to change the font-size of the last 2 characters in an input field on an HTML site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an input field, with a changed value. The value changes through a javascript function. This is always a decimal number.

The decimal number's last 2 digits shall have a different font-size: 10 px

```js
function generate(){
   var generatedValue=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)/100.0;
   document.getElementById("myinput").value = generatedValue;
};
```

```css
body{
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.inputClass {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

    <div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
      <input id="myinput" class="form-control inputClass" value="0.00" disabled>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as a side note: print `generatedValue.toFixed(2)`or you'll get a single decimal in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use more than one font-size inside an input element, so you need to use a different element styled in the same way (e.g an  [`output`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) element)

In the example below I kept the input element as an `hidden` element in case you need it for a data pass in a form

```js
function generate(){
   var generatedValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)/100.0;
   var result = generatedValue.toFixed(2);
   var amount = result.split('.');
   
   document.getElementById("myinput").value = result;
   document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = amount[0] + '.<small>' + amount[1] + '</small>';
   
};
```

```css
body{
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.inputClass, output {
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}


/* Declarations taken from the style applied to .inputClass */
div output {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #e9ecef;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
  color: #495057;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

    <div class="input-group" class="numberDiv">
      <input id="myinput" class="form-control inputClass" value="0.00" disabled type="hidden" />
      <output>0.<small>00</small></output>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like more result fields
You need to change result,  and 
Example :

```
var amount = result. split('.');
var amount2 = result2 .split('.');
document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = amount[0]+'.<small>' + amount[1] + '</small>';
document.querySelector('output2').innerHTML = amount2 [0]+'.<small>' + amount2 [1]+'</small>';
```

Etc ..